# \vbox and vertical spacing between lines

Tags: boxes, line-spacing

When I put a text in a `\vbox` and `\unvbox` it, I have extra space between line.

Why?

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newbox\titi
\newcommand{\toto}[1]{\setbox\titi=\vbox{#1}\unvbox\titi}
{\LARGE\toto{Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.}}

{\LARGE Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The paragraph in the `\vbox` is completed when `\LARGE` is in effect. It isn't in the second example, because `\par` is after `}`. Add `\par` before `}` and you'll see the same baselineskip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code

```
{\LARGE Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.}
```

is followed by `\end{document}`, which does `\par`. However, this `\par` comes after the effect of `\LARGE` has been undone, so the baselineskip used is what's pertains to `\normalsize` (and the `\lineskip` mechanism comes into play).

In the `\vbox` this doesn't happen, because the end of a `\vbox` has an implicit `\par` command, which is issued when `\LARGE` is still in effect.

If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newbox\titi
\newcommand{\toto}[1]{\setbox\titi=\vbox{#1}\unvbox\titi}
{\LARGE\toto{Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.}}

{\LARGE Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.\par}
\end{document}
```

you'll get the same output.

[image]

By the way, recall that TeX doesn't add interline glue when it does `\unvbox`. So with

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newbox\titi
\newcommand{\toto}[1]{\setbox\titi=\vbox{#1}\unvbox\titi}
{\LARGE Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.\par}

{\LARGE\toto{Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Sic transit gloria mundi. Fiat Lux. In principio erat verbum.}}
\end{document}
```

you'd get

[image]

Comment: nice and elaborate answer as usual. :-)

Comment: We should have some knowledge base where we can collect small important facts like "TeX doesn't add interline glue when it does `\unvbox`"